# Adding class to menu item not changing styling

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to add a class to menu links when clicked as described in this tutorial using element.classList.add method. I can see the link items get the active class when inspecting the elements in the console but the styling is not changing. Thank you.

Complete project can be seen [here](http://z1labs.com/projects/landingpage).

JS

```
const links = document.querySelectorAll('#navbar__list li a');
links.forEach(function(link) {

    link.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      
        links.forEach(function(element) { 
            element.classList.add('active-link');
        });
    });

});
```

css

```
.active_link {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
}]
```

Comment: What's that `]` doing in your CSS? What does your HTML look like? You should probably use `event.preventDefault()` to stop any page navigation (unless you actually want to navigate but then why bother adding a class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in the class that you are adding. It should be

```
element.classList.add('active_link');
```

as per your class declaration.

Also, you don't need to loop inside your event listener else the class will be applied to all the links

Answer (score 0):

Update the answer since others mentioned the typo, class should be 'active_link'

```
links.forEach(ele => {
    ele.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
          console.log('clicked');
        ele.classList.add('active_link');
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

class you are adding via JS is **active-link** and class which is defined in css file is **active_link** both the string are different